# Deploy to both Google Play and Samsung Apps

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, updates, samsung-mobile

I am wondering do I need to change the package name on Samsung app store (or whatever its called) or can I just use the same package name. I ask because if I upload to Google play, then again I upload to Samsung apps with the same package name(same app basically), then will there be conflicts between Google play and Samsung app when it comes to updating and such.

Scenario
User downloads my app on Samsung device (lets say S4) from the Samsung app store, I have that same app (same package and everything, except one uses Google in app purchases while the other uses Samsung in app purchases) on Google play. Since the S4 has both Samsung app store and Google play, will for instance Google play try to update my Samsung store download if a newer version is available via google play and not yet available via samsung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that there is a naming conflict if the packages are the same. I cant remember where I saw it but a couple users said that sometimes Google Play will try to update the apps download via Samsung apps and fail. So it does cause some conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Your apps can have the same package id on both stores. In fact, you can store the same apk to both stores if you dont need any customized behavior for Samsung builds.
The application then be updated via either of Stores. I have been using this for last 1 year or so and didn't find any problems.